# Return a List<?> based on recieved parameters

Tags: c#

So, I'm writing a method to get tables from a database. I want to make it dynamic to avoid writing a new method for each table. it's something like this:

```
public static List<?> LoadTable(string TableName, Class class)
{
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            var output = cnn.Query<class>("select * from " + TableName, new DynamicParameters());
            return output.ToList();
        }
}
```

now the problem is, when I write `"List<dynamic>"` instead of the `"List<?>"` it can't convert the class to dynamic. also the parameter "Class class" is not valid obviously. how can I get a class type like that? "Type" doesn't work either as you know.

Comment: Change your method to use generics: `public static List<T> LoadTable<T>(string TableName, T class)`

Comment: Further, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You can make the method generic instead. `Query<T>` is generic, which allows it to handle any class.

Comment: MartinCostello and PanagiotisKanavos thanks a huge lot! I used both your suggestions and it works like a charm!

Comment: @MartinCostello btw is SQL injection possible in C# desktop apps? this application is going to work in a private computer with no unapproved user anywhere close to it but your suggestion made me wonder.

Comment: Regardless of use case, the code **is** vulnerable. Whether the vulnerability can be used **in practice** depends on whether users can specify the table names or not.

Comment: You could use Entity Framework too...

Comment: @MartinCostello great to know, I'll do more research about that, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ergis yea but it's a sqlite application and I want to keep it simple and fast. needing to update the data model of Entity Framework every time I change the database is one reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MartinCostello and @PanagiotisKanavos comments, we come to a great answer for my simple but frustrating problem:

```
public static List<T> LoadTable<T>(string TableName)
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
    {
            var output = cnn.Query<T>("select * from " + dBTable, new DynamicParameters());
            return output.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadTable<TableClass>("TableName");
```